# How can you use an environmental variable with an npm package

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, secret-key, npm-package

I have an npm package(written in node.js) that creates a GitHUb repository. I want to update the authorization to use an OAuth token. The Oauth token needs a client id and and a client secret which I need to keep secret. How do I include that in the npm package without revealing the information and compromising my credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include the token in your package, instead you would read it from your environment. You can then read those variables in your package.

For example, if you export the variables as environment variables, you can read them via [`procss.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env).

```js
var clientId = process.env.MY_CLIENT_ID;
var clientSecret = process.env.MY_CLIENT_SECRET;

console.log(clientId, clientSecret);
```

Then in your shell or dot files that init your shell, you can simple export the values.

```sh
export MY_CLIENT_ID='myid'
export MY_CLIENT_SECRET='mysecret'
```

For use with a continuous integration service, there should be a way to create secret or hidden environment variables ([for example with Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/)).

---

Alternately, if you need to use those same credentials, and you don't want people to be able to access those credentials, you would have to setup a server that accepts requests from clients and performs those actions using your credentials.

Comment: Does that break the package for people who don't have my credentials in their environments?

Comment: @joshhahn Yes, you can't give them your credentials, without them being able to access them. Instead they should be using their own credentials, or perhaps making a request to a server you run which processes their request.

Comment: ok so If I have a server running the request using my credentials and make an api call to that server to get the info I need then I can secure my credentials?

Comment: @joshhahn Yep, the server would be the only thing that should see and use those credentials.

Comment: Just one more clarification I can set an environmental variable for a server hosted on Heroku correct?

Comment: @joshhahn Cool, I've updated my answer with this method. And yes, [you can set environment variables on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).